# integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4y^2\ln (xy)} dx dy$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4y^2\ln (xy)} dx dy$$
Any ideas on this one?

Comment: You sure bounds are right?

Comment: Are you supposed to know about the exponential integral function ?

Comment: The bounds are fine. The antiderivative is not ($\rm{Ei}$ and stuff), but we don't really need it, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first change to the variables $u=xy,\;v=x/y$ (the Jacobian is $1\over2v$), and the thing becomes
$$\int\limits_1^\infty\int\limits_{1/u}^u{1\over2u^3v^2\ln u}dv\;du$$
Now take the inner integral and get
$$\int\limits_1^\infty{u^2-1\over2u^4\ln u}du$$
Now is the time for some complex machinery. A common trick with introducing a parameter would do. Say, we have $u^t$ instead of $u^2$ in the numerator; that would be $F(t)$. Then $F'(t)=\int\limits_1^\infty{u^t\over2u^4}du={1\over2(3-t)}$, and $F(0)=0$, so we may reconstruct $F(2)$ which we need.

Comment: Very nice. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Good point..${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, any idea why I get -1/2v for Jacobian?


$${\left| J \right|^{ - 1}} = \left| {\matrix{
   {{{\partial u} \over {\partial x}}} & {{{\partial u} \over {\partial y}}}  \cr 
   {{{\partial v} \over {\partial x}}} & {{{\partial v} \over {\partial y}}}  \cr 

 } } \right| = \left| {\matrix{
   y & x  \cr 
   {{1 \over y}} & { - {x \over {{y^2}}}}  \cr 

 } } \right| =  - {x \over y} - {x \over y} =  - 2{x \over y} =  - 2v$$

Comment: Plus or minus, who cares. Anyway, at any given step we are integrating a strictly positive function and getting a positive value. The minus must have been reversed by some direction change later on.